# SemVer: can new functionality be considered breaking change?

Tags: java, scala, semantic-versioning

Consider a library that defines a class A, with several methods (A1, A2, ...), at version 1.0.0 (semantic versioning)

Now imagine I add a new method to A object (method Ab). Is this a minor release? Because it adds functionality, and it shouldn't be a breaking change. 
But if someone who's using the library declared a class A that extends class B, and B defines a method Ab with the same signature than the new method, now the code won't compile because it required the override declaration (in Scala and Java).

So, is this a breaking change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, adding a public method to a class in general is not a breaking change in semantic versioning. Removing a public method however would be a clear breaking change.

If you provide a Java library and you **add** a method to an `interface`, this **is** a breaking change, since others have to change / extend their code.

If you **add** a public method to a `class`, this will only be a problem, if this class is *not final*, so other can extend it and override methods.

So the best way I think is to declare a `class` as final, so the problem with method override should never happen. You can also leave the major update and only increase the minor one. Adding methods to interfaces will be a breaking change, so there you should increase the major version.

Comment: So we can say that it somehow depends on the programming language?
It's rare to declare a class as final in Java/Scala from my experience.

But should we say that adding a public method to a (not final) class is a breaking change?

Comment: In my opinion, SemVer does not depend on the programming language. But the programming language and their usage for libraries defines the way you have to update the version to follow it.

Comment: Personally I would not define it as major change If I add a public method to a class. But to be strict, I think you should if it is not final.